# Как исправить ошибку No setter/field for translation found on class com.nikita.mozhaev.vocabulary.Word

Tags: android, firebase

как исправить ошибку
W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for translation found on class com.nikita.mozhaev.vocabulary.Word
Пытаюсь парсить данные с realtime database.
Вот код:
**FirebaseHelper.java**

```
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;

import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class FirebaseDatabaseHelper {

    private FirebaseDatabase mDatabase;
    private DatabaseReference mRefenceWords;
    private List<Word> words = new ArrayList<>();

    public interface DataStatus{
        void DataIsLoaded(List<Word> words, List<String> keys);
        void DataIsInserted();
        void DataIsUpdated();
        void DataIsDeleted();
    }

    public FirebaseDatabaseHelper(){
        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        mRefenceWords = mDatabase.getReference("Words");

    }

    public void readWords(final DataStatus dataStatus){
        mRefenceWords.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                words.clear();
                List<String> keys = new ArrayList<>();
                for (DataSnapshot keyNode : snapshot.getChildren()){
                    keys.add(keyNode.getKey());
                    Word word = keyNode.getValue(Word.class);
                    words.add(word);
                }

                dataStatus.DataIsLoaded(words, keys);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

**RecyclerView_config.java**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.List;

public class RecyclerView_config {

    private Context mContext;
    private WordAdapter mWordAdapter;
    public void setConfig(RecyclerView recyclerView, Context context, List<Word> words, List<String> keys){
        mContext = context;
        mWordAdapter = new WordAdapter(words, keys);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(mWordAdapter);
    }

    class WordItemView extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        private TextView mWord;
        private TextView mTranslate;


        private String key;

        public WordItemView(ViewGroup parent){
            super(LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.word_item, parent, false));
        }
        public void bind(Word word, String key){
            mWord.setText(word.getWord());
            mTranslate.setText(word.getTranslate());
            this.key = key;
        }
    }

    class WordAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<WordItemView>{
        private List<Word> mWordList;
        private List<String> mKeys;

        public WordAdapter(List<Word> mWordList, List<String> mKeys){
            this.mWordList = mWordList;
            this.mKeys = mKeys;
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public WordItemView onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            return new WordItemView(parent);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull WordItemView holder, int position) {
            holder.bind(mWordList.get(position), mKeys.get(position));

        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return 0;
        }
    }

}
```

**MainActivity.java**

````
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
    
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.Toast;
    
    import com.google.firebase.database.ChildEventListener;
    import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
    import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
    import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
    import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
    
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;
    
    import static android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1;
    
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    
        RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
        FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;
        DatabaseReference databaseReference;
    
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    
    
            firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
            databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference("Words");
    
            mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerview_words);
            Toast.makeText(this, "ok", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    
            new FirebaseDatabaseHelper().readWords(new FirebaseDatabaseHelper.DataStatus() {
                @Override
                public void DataIsLoaded(List<Word> words, List<String> keys) {
                    new RecyclerView_config().setConfig(mRecyclerView, MainActivity.this, words, keys);
                }
    
                @Override
                public void DataIsInserted() {
    
                }
    
                @Override
                public void DataIsUpdated() {
    
                }
    
                @Override
                public void DataIsDeleted() {
    
                }
            });
        }
    } 
    ```
    **activity_main.xml**
    ```
 

       <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/linear"
            tools:context=".MainActivity">
        
        
                <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/recyclerview_words"
                    android:layout_width="411dp"
                    android:layout_height="730dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
        
        
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

 
Word.java
````

public class Word {

```
    private String word;
    private String translate;

    public Word(){}

    public void setWord(String name)
    {
        this.word = name;
    }

    public String getWord()
    {
        return word;
    }

    public String getTranslate() {
        return translate;
    }

    public void setTranslate(String translate) {
        this.translate = translate;
    }
```

**word_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/main_trans"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="184dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="184dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="77dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="77dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="684dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/main_word"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/main_word"
        android:text="Translate"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/main_word"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="Word"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Переименовать поля дата-класса в соответствии с полями в базе, либо указать правильные имена аннотацией `@PropertyName("translation")` на геттерах/сеттерах

Comment: @woesss, а где конкретно это ставить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка говорит о том, что для поля `"translation"` из базы не найдено соответствие в дата-классе - библиотека будет искать `public` поле `translation`, либо `public` методы `getTranslation` и `setTranslation` либо любые `public` поля и подходящие по сигнатуре методы, помеченные аннотацией `@PropertyName("translation")`.
Чтобы исправить ошибку нужно выполнить любое из перечисленных условий

```
public class Word {

        private String word;
        private String translation;

        public Word(){}

        public void setWord(String name)
        {
            this.word = name;
        }

        public String getWord()
        {
            return word;
        }

        @PropertyName("translation")
        public String getTranslation() {
            return translate;
        }

        @PropertyName("translation")
        public void setTranslation(String translation) {
            this.translation = translation;
        }
```

Comment: А, что делать, если эта ошибка ушла, но пришла вот такая ошибка?
E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout

Comment: Принять ответ и задать новый вопрос с новой ошибкой, желательно попытавшись найти решение самостоятельно.